# Isn't "video documentaries about physics?" too broad?

Tags: discussion, scope, resource-recommendation

This question was recently bumped to the front page: [Video documentaries about physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9874/video-documentaries-about-physics). It lay dormant for many years, which explains why it wasn't closed under the previous absolutely-not [books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) policy. Now that we have a more permissive policy on resource recommendation requests, the question is in principle on-topic, but I feel that

#### this question is too broad to be a good [books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) question.

While the idea of asking for documentaries is, I think, quite nice, such threads ought to be confined to much more specific topics. Otherwise,

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.

What say ye?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, for all the reasons you listed. I have flagged and voted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I immediately voted "too broad" when I saw it.  I think our aggressive closing of closing of homework questions has made us twitchy about closing things.  A lot of the questions are interesting but off topic questions that would be closed (rightly so) by today's standards.